# Returning a toString from a StringBuffer

Tags: java

This is my class:

```
    public String toString(){
    status = status1.getStat();
    item = status1.getItem();
    boolean checked;
    checked = false;
    StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("");
    StringBuffer s1, s2, s3, z;
    s1 = new StringBuffer(item1[1]+"["+item2[1]+"] ");
    s2 = new StringBuffer(item1[2]+"["+item2[2]+"] ");
    s3 = new StringBuffer(item1[3]+"["+item2[3]+"] ");
    z = new StringBuffer(" player("+player+") - "+points+" points ");
    //sb1.append(item1[1]+"["+item2[1]+"] "+item1[2]+"["+item2[2]+"] "+ item1[3]+"["+item2[3]+"] "+ "player("+player+") - "+points+" points ");

    if (status == 1 && item.equals(item1[1])){
        item1[1] = "*"; 
        s1 = sb1.append(item1[1]+" ");
        //sb1.delete(1,4);
    }else if (status == 1 && item.equals(item1[2])){
        item1[2] = "*";
        s2 = sb1.append(item1[2]+" ");

    }else if(status == 1 && item.equals(item1[3])){
        item1[3] = "*";
        s3 = sb1.append(item1[3]+" ");

    }  

    return s1.toString()+s2.toString()+s3.toString()+z.toString();
```

My output is the following:

```
Let: 
 item1[1] = Alpha
 item2[1] = 1
 item3[1] = 0
 -----
 item1[2] = Beta
 item2[2] = 1
 item2[2] = 0
 -----
 item1[3] = Charlie
 item2[3] = 2
```

My output is:

```
when status = 1 and item = item1[1]
--
* Beta[1] Charlie[2]
--
When run the code for the second time
*[1] * Charlie[2]
--
When i run the code for the third time
*[1] *[1] Charlie[2]
```

Is it possible to make it like the following?

```
when status = 1 and item = item1[1]
--
* Beta[1] Charlie[2]
--
When run the code for the second time
*  * Charlie[2]
--
When i run the code for the third time
* * *
```

This will need to happen in random order.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want `toString()` to return different values each time it is called for the same object?

Comment: Yes, if the conditions are met, i want it to rename item1 to * and remove the [ ] around item2

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of `toString()` that returned different strings randomly does not match the declared semantics.  The javadoc for `Object.toString()` says:

> In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read.

If you want to randomly display different parts or aspects of an object, you should call the method something different.

Indeed, you should consider factoring the randomization out of the class entirely; e.g.

```
    Random r = ...
    ...
    YourClass yc = ...
    int nosParts = yc.getNosParts();
    int partNo = r.nextInt(nosParts);
    String str = yc.getPartAsString(partNo);
```

or

```
    int[] perm = ... // randomly permuted array of [0 .. nosParts - 1]
    for (int i = 0; i < nosParts; i++) {
        String str = yc.getPartAsString(perm[i]);
        ...
    }
```

This approach has the advantage that your class is easier to test, is more reusable, and doesn't have the burden of remembering what happened in previous calls to the String rendering method.